# PHP quote vs single quote

Tags: php, double-quotes, quote

Hello I have a function like this

```
function find($start, $end, $data)
{
@preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') .
'(.*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/i', $data, $m);
return @$m[1];}
```

I am taking a data from url.

```
$var= find('<div class='abc'>','</div>',$url);
```

But this gives me syntax error. I think it considers as closing quote the one before abc. like this '

Comment: There is no syntax error in the function shown.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$var= find('<div class='abc'>','</div>',$url);
```

Into this:

```
$var= find('<div class="abc">','</div>',$url);
```

Or, this:

```
$var= find('<div class=\'abc\'>','</div>',$url);
```

Or, this:

```
$var= find("<div class='abc'>",'</div>',$url);
```

Single quotes and double quotes can be intermixed but they need to be escaped with a backslash (`\`) when you want to use the same within the variable definition to allow it to work.

This is valid:

```
$var = "'this works'";
$var = "'";
$var = "\"this works\"";
$var = '"this works"';
$var = '\'this works\'';
```

This is invalid:

```
$var = ''this will not work'';
$var = ""will not work"";
```

Comment: None of these worked. It still says Undefined Offset:0 .

Comment: Also I cannot says this : $var= find('<div class="abc">','</div>',$url);

Comment: Because in page source it is written like <div class='abc'>.

Comment: what error is the line happening on? can you edit your question to include any changes you made to the code?  try to provide as much information as possible and hopefully we can figure this out.

Comment: I didnot change the code. I tried what you said and it gave this error : "Undefined offset: 0 at line $var= find('<div class="abc">','</div>',$url);"

Comment: Can you remove the at (@) symbols from your function and see what errors, if any, happen then? The error you're describing doesn't really match what is happening in that line of code and the at symbols can suppress error messages. Is there any other code surrounding it?